# Does pytorch support multiple tensor CAddTable?

Tags: pytorch

I found in [official doc](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/nnft_tutorial.html) that CAddTable should be done as

```
x = x1 + x2 # instead of CAddTable(x1, x2) in older version
```

and PyTorch would do the rest of things like autograd

But how about if I have multiple tensors, aka. changing the input above from two tensors to a list of tensors. Could PyTorch still do the similar things?

Comment: Yes, just `x = x1 + x2 + x3 + ...` then Pytorch will help you to handle autograd.

Comment: @cao-nv what if the forward takes non-determined args, like `forward(x*)`, which could take arbitrary length of a list(or a stack of tensors), and if I do a for loop like `y = torch.zeros(x_shape)` and  `y += i for i in x` in this case, would it still works?

Comment: sure, 100% work for the first case. In the later one, you want to sum `x` along the first dimension?

Comment: @cao-nv yes, this also counts. The purpose is to add multiple tensors. Adding a list of tensors or adding first dimensions across a stacked tensor both fit the requirement.

Comment: Oh, I see. You can conveniently do both of your purposes by using `torch.sum` and `torch.stack` easily.
```python
x = torch.stack((x1, x2, x3, x4), dim=0)
y = torch.sum(x, dim=0, keepdim=False)
```
`y` will have the same shape as `x1, x2, x3...`

Comment: @cao-nv got it! You could post it in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for a clean display of the code snip in the comment:

```py
x = torch.stack((x1, x2, x3, x4), dim=0)
y = torch.sum(x, dim=0, keepdim=False) # same shape as x1, x2...
```